# 'function' object has no attribute 'item'

Tags: python

I wrote a function to train a simple linear regression model.
after running my training function I see this error:
'function' object has no attribute 'item'

```
def train (x,y,w,b,alpha,epoch):
train_error = []

  for e in range (epoch):
    w,b = update_w_b(x,y,w,b,alpha)
    train_error.append(avg_loss.item())

#process monitoring
if e%400 == 0:
  print ("epoch: {}/{} \t loss: {:.4f}".format(e+1,epoch,avg_loss(x,y,w,b)))
  return w,b,train_errorenter code here
```

Thanks all

Comment: `avg_loss` is not defined in the code as posted.

Comment: You haven't given a clue as to what `avg_loss.item()` is supposed to mean. This question can't be meaningfully answered. When you ask a question, please remember that those reading the question don't already know the context of the question.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code has both syntax errors and undefined symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, `avg_loss` is a function, because you call it as such on the second to last line of your code, and the error message you're getting suggests that it is as well.

You also try to access an attribute on `avg_loss` named `item`.  A function has no such attribute, as the error message is telling you.  So the line:

```
train_error.append(avg_loss.item())
```

is invalid syntax.  You must mean to do something different here...I'm not sure what.

Comment: this is my los_avg function;